# How to pass `self` to a method-like object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7, monkeypatching

If I patch a class's **method** with a **function**, the function behaves like a method, with `self` being passed as the first of the `args`.

```
class Spam:
    pass

def eggs( *args ):
    return args

Spam.eggs = eggs
spam = Spam()
print( spam.eggs() ) # ---> (<Spam>, )
                     #      all good!
```

However, if I patch using an **object** (with `.__call__`) instance, then `self` is no longer passed as an argument:

```
class Spam:
    pass

class Beans:
    def __call__( *args ):
        return args

Spam.beans = Beans()
spam = Spam()
print( spam.beans() ) # ---> (<Beans>, )
                      #      - not good, I'd expect this to be
                      #        (<Beans>, <Spam>, )
```

- **In the above example, why has Python decided that the `Spam` `self` will longer be passed?**
- **How can I get `Spam` `self` to be passed?**

*Rationale: For the purposes of caching return values, I'd like to modify my class's functions (actually using decorators rather than monkeypatching - but that is beyond the scope of this question). Rather than replace my class's methods with functions, I'd like to use class objects, because it makes for nicer code by allowing me to preserve the state in objects instead of  trying to fix all the closures using `lambda`s.*

Comment: Very closely related: [How can I decorate an instance method with a decorator class?](//stackoverflow.com/q/30104047)

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is function objects that are called as methods, and just defining `__call__` makes the class a "callable", but not a function object (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

To fix it, you can make the class a descriptor:

```
class Spam:
    pass

class Beans:
    def __call__( *args ):
        return args

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        from functools import partial
        return partial(self.__call__, instance)

Spam.beans = Beans()
spam = Spam()
print(spam.beans())
```

gets

```
(<__main__.Beans object at 0x00000179F17664E0>, <__main__.Spam object at 0x00000179F1757F98>)
```